# messaging between clients without polling

Tags: client-server, message-queue, messaging, amqp, service-broker

I have a network of MS SQL servers connected to each other with (C++/C#)clients connected to them. and I'm about designing a way of messaging between clients and server-client messaging.
I've alread read about MS SQL Service Broker and other Brokers like Apache Qpid.
but still I cant find out how would this work, I would be thankful is someone could provide me with better sources or if someone has already worked with such an issue.

How could I make sending and recieving messages between clients without  possible?

and please make sure this is no school homework or university course project.

I would really appreciate any helpful comment or advice...

+++Thanks+++

Comment: What type of messages are you sending back and forth?  And are you planning a broker/server?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I cant find out how would this work"?  You can't find any code?  Techincal (architecture) information? Conceptually? Please clarify.

Comment: I mean Techincal (architecture) information with code examples maybe..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN has quite a bit of technical information regarding SQL Service Broker.  It is fairly high-level, but if you dig / read enough you will be a pro in no time.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166043%28SQL.90%29.aspx

There are also a bunch of useful code samples floating around on the internet that should get you up and running so you can start experimenting.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_service_broker/
http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1836

Best of Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Why not poll? It's easy, the "dumbest thing that could possibly work".

I suggest you consider polling unless you have established what the problem with polling is.

Considerations:

1. Timeliness. How quickly must the message be recieved?
2. Frequency. How many messages are sent to each client per hour? Per day?

Plus, if your application has a connection heartbeat anyway, you could have it report whether there are any new messages and kill two birds with one stone.

Comment: well Ben, I dont prefer polling because it causes traffic which reduces the performance of my network with the load it going to cause, in addition of that I can't forecast messaging traffic, there is no frequent in messages. a message could be sent today and next day maybe hundred messages. Thats why not polling. I prefer pusging messages than polling it ;)

so what do you think?

Comment: @A.R., Sometimes when someone says "how do I do X" the best answer is "don't do X do Y". That's the case here. @user660558, how much traffic? A few hundred bytes, literally a couple of network packets. Polling is simple, should take half a day to implement, and will be a teeny-tiny fraction of your network traffic. My advice is be sure you know **why** polling is not good enough before you reject it. **Do the numbers**.

Comment: The question stands on its own.  User** is asking how to solve a problem within a set of limits, not what the community thinks is 'the best design'.  We don't have the gooey details of the project, and don't need them.  He can decide for himself what is best after his question has been answered.

Comment: @A.R. We will have to agree to disagree. You go ahead and help him do the thing he is asking to do. I will advise him do something I think is more appropriate to his actual task. He can choose which is best advice and so can the rest of the community.

Answer (score 0):

If you are affraid of doing a

```
//PSUDO Code
while(!stopped){
   try{
     message = receiver.fetch(timeout);
   }catch(TimeoutException){
     //handle
   }

}
```

You could always prefetch, set the prefetch:

```
  receiver.setCapacity(100);
```

and then you could use the available messages functionality, but in all reality, this sounds like polling, in a backwards way ;)

Comment: may be publish/subscribe?
bcoz my messages are notifications that have catigories.. what do you think?